# How can I make my dataset continuous with respect to time? [R]

Tags: r

I have a dataset for x, y date and time.

My Initial dataset is :

```
x    y   date    time
1    2    1-1-01  15:00
2    5    1-1-01  17:00
3    1    1-1-01  18:00
5    7    1-1-01  21:00
2    6    1-1-01  22:00
6    3    1-1-01  23:00
9    2    2-1-01  01:00
6    1    2-1-01  04:00
.....
```

I want it as:

```
x    y   date    time
1    2    1-1-01  15:00
n/a n/a   1-1-01  16:00
2    5    1-1-01  17:00
3    1    1-1-01  18:00
n/a n/a   1-1-01  19:00
n/a n/a   1-1-01  20:00
5    7    1-1-01  21:00
2    6    1-1-01  22:00
6    3    1-1-01  23:00
n/a n/a   2-1-01  00:00
9    2    2-1-01  01:00
n/a n/a   2-1-01  02:00
n/a n/a   2-1-01  03:00
6    1    2-1-01  04:00
.....
```

How can I fill n/a values?

I tried to use xspline function to interpolate the 'x' and 'y'

```
plot(df[,2:1])
xspline(df[,2:1], shape=-0.3, lwd=1)
```

Using this plot can I find the values for n/a or is there any other way to find the values for n/a?

Comment: @akrun how can I match that with my time. Actually, in reality I have manually written those rows which are having n/a to make my data continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create another dataset with sequence of 'time' grouped by 'date' and join with the original dataset.  This can be done using the `devel` version of `data.table`.  Instructions to install the devel version are [`here`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

```
library(data.table)
DT <- setDT(df1)[, {tmp <- as.numeric(substr(time,1,2))
  list(time=sprintf('%02d:00', min(tmp):max(tmp)))}, date]
df1[DT, on=c('date', 'time')]
# x  y   date  time
# 1:  1  2 1-1-01 15:00
# 2: NA NA 1-1-01 16:00
# 3:  2  5 1-1-01 17:00
# 4:  3  1 1-1-01 18:00
# 5: NA NA 1-1-01 19:00
# 6: NA NA 1-1-01 20:00
# 7:  5  7 1-1-01 21:00
# 8:  2  6 1-1-01 22:00
# 9:  6  3 1-1-01 23:00
#10:  9  2 2-1-01 01:00
#11: NA NA 2-1-01 02:00
#12: NA NA 2-1-01 03:00
#13:  6  1 2-1-01 04:00
```

Or if we wanted to create 'time' `00` to `23` hours and then delete the rows that are NA before the first non-NA value in 'x' and 'y' and similar for rows that are NA after the last non-NAs

```
 DT <- setDT(df1)[, list(time=sprintf('%02d:00', 0:23)) , date]
 res <- df1[DT, on=c('date', 'time')
             ][,{tmp <- which(!(is.na(x) & is.na(y)))
            .SD[tmp[1L]:tmp[length(tmp)]]}]
 res 
 # x  y   date  time
 #1:  1  2 1-1-01 15:00
 #2: NA NA 1-1-01 16:00
 #3:  2  5 1-1-01 17:00
 #4:  3  1 1-1-01 18:00
 #5: NA NA 1-1-01 19:00
 #6: NA NA 1-1-01 20:00
 #7:  5  7 1-1-01 21:00
 #8:  2  6 1-1-01 22:00
 #9:  6  3 1-1-01 23:00
 #10:NA NA 2-1-01 00:00
 #11: 9  2 2-1-01 01:00
 #12:NA NA 2-1-01 02:00
 #13:NA NA 2-1-01 03:00
 #14: 6  1 2-1-01 04:00
```

I didn't read the last part.  If you need to fill the NA values, as @bdecaf mentioned in the post (and the same thing I commented and removed earlier), you can use `na.approx` from `library(zoo)`

```
library(zoo)
res[, c('x', 'y') :=lapply(.SD, na.approx), .SDcols= x:y]
#           x        y   date  time
# 1: 1.000000 2.000000 1-1-01 15:00
# 2: 1.500000 3.500000 1-1-01 16:00
# 3: 2.000000 5.000000 1-1-01 17:00
# 4: 3.000000 1.000000 1-1-01 18:00
# 5: 3.666667 3.000000 1-1-01 19:00
# 6: 4.333333 5.000000 1-1-01 20:00
# 7: 5.000000 7.000000 1-1-01 21:00
# 8: 2.000000 6.000000 1-1-01 22:00
# 9: 6.000000 3.000000 1-1-01 23:00
#10: 7.500000 2.500000 2-1-01 00:00
#11: 9.000000 2.000000 2-1-01 01:00
#12: 8.000000 1.666667 2-1-01 02:00
#13: 7.000000 1.333333 2-1-01 03:00
#14: 6.000000 1.000000 2-1-01 04:00
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(x = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 9L, 6L), y = c(2L, 
5L, 1L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 1L), date = c("1-1-01", "1-1-01", "1-1-01", 
"1-1-01", "1-1-01", "1-1-01", "2-1-01", "2-1-01"), time = c("15:00", 
"17:00", "18:00", "21:00", "22:00", "23:00", "01:00", "04:00"
)), .Names = c("x", "y", "date", "time"), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Comment: akrun.. this solution is producing an `Error [.data.table(df1, DT, on = c("date", "time")) : unused argument (on = c("date", "time"))`

Comment: @Flames As I mentioned in the description, I am using the devel version of data.table.  Which version do you have?

Comment: I guess its the same.

Comment: @Flames Based on the dput data, I am not getting any error though.

Comment: @Flames Try `setkey(df1, date, time)[DT]`

Answer (score 2):

### about getting the required table

you can do this in base r:

**Data**

```
in.data <- read.table(text='x    y    date    time
1    2    1-1-01  15:00
2    5    1-1-01  17:00
3    1    1-1-01  18:00
5    7    1-1-01  21:00
2    6    1-1-01  22:00
6    3    1-1-01  23:00
9    2    2-1-01  1:00
6    1    2-1-01  4:00
', header=TRUE)

times <- paste0(0:23,':00')
dates <- paste0(1:2,'-1-01')
```

**create wanted table**

```
all.dt <- expand.grid(date=dates,time=times)

big.data <- merge(all.dt, in.data, all.x=TRUE)
```

### about filling the nas:

tools provided by [zoo](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/index.html)

They have numerous functions to deal with this problem: `na.approx`, `na.spline` and `na.locf`. E.g.

```
library(zoo)
big.data <- within(big.data,{
         x <- na.approx(x,na.rm=FALSE)
         y <- na.approx(y,na.rm=FALSE)
})
```

big.data then contains:

```
     date  time        x        y
1  1-1-01  0:00       NA       NA
2  1-1-01  1:00       NA       NA
...
15 1-1-01 14:00       NA       NA
16 1-1-01 15:00 1.000000 2.000000
17 1-1-01 16:00 1.500000 3.500000
18 1-1-01 17:00 2.000000 5.000000
19 1-1-01 18:00 3.000000 1.000000
20 1-1-01 19:00 3.666667 3.000000
21 1-1-01 20:00 4.333333 5.000000
22 1-1-01 21:00 5.000000 7.000000
23 1-1-01 22:00 2.000000 6.000000
24 1-1-01 23:00 6.000000 3.000000
25 2-1-01  0:00 7.500000 2.500000
26 2-1-01  1:00 9.000000 2.000000
27 2-1-01  2:00 8.000000 1.666667
28 2-1-01  3:00 7.000000 1.333333
29 2-1-01  4:00 6.000000 1.000000
30 2-1-01  5:00       NA       NA
31 2-1-01  6:00       NA       NA
...
```