# Setting time intervals for a plot [R]

Tags: r

To my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31624087/how-can-i-make-my-dataset-continuous-with-respect-to-time-r), from the dataset, How can I use it for 20 minutes time interval.

I tried both of the solution but both of them are showing same results. My data set isn't taking all the values when I am trying to convert it to a different time interval (say 20 minute).

Is it possible to convert it into data.frame() instead rather than data.table(). This is one of the answer given by akrun:

```
x    y   date    time
1    2    1-1-01  15:00
2    5    1-1-01  17:00
3    1    1-1-01  18:00
5    7    1-1-01  21:00
2    6    1-1-01  22:00
6    3    1-1-01  23:00
9    2    2-1-01  01:00
6    1    2-1-01  04:00
.....

library(data.table)
DT <- setDT(df1)[, {tmp <- as.numeric(substr(time,1,2))
list(time=sprintf('%02d:00', min(tmp):max(tmp)))}, date]
df1[DT, on=c('date', 'time')]
DT <- setDT(df1)[, list(time=sprintf('%02d:00', 0:23)) , date]
res <- df1[DT, on=c('date', 'time')
         ][,{tmp <- which(!(is.na(x) & is.na(y)))
        .SD[tmp[1L]:tmp[length(tmp)]]}]
res 

library(zoo)
res[, c('x', 'y') :=lapply(.SD, na.approx), .SDcols= x:y]
```

Comment: Can you please encapsulate the whole code here?

Comment: Your original data is one hour interval. Tell us how x and y are going to be divided in 20 min interval, just proportionally? or you have the high frequency data?

Comment: @Robert Yes, proportionally..  I do have high frequency data but it is not continuous... At times i have minutes data but sometimes I have time intervals in hrs.. so I am trying to have a moderate dataset..

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I have encapsulated the code.. can you please look at the question again.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Requested to run the following code...

```
df1 <- structure(list(x = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 9L, 6L), y = c(2L, 
5L, 1L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 1L), date = c("1-1-01", "1-1-01", "1-1-01", 
"1-1-01", "1-1-01", "1-1-01", "2-1-01", "2-1-01"), time = c("15:00", 
"17:00", "18:00", "21:00", "22:00", "23:00", "01:00", "04:00"
)), .Names = c("x", "y", "date", "time"), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, -8L))


library(chron)
library(data.table)


time<-as.character(substr(times(00:71/72),1,5))
dates <- paste0(1:2,'-1-01')

all.dt <- expand.grid(date=dates,time=time)
big.data <- merge(all.dt, df1, all.x=TRUE)
```

Now for the last part you can fill NA by running the following code

```
library(zoo)
big.data <- within(big.data,{
         x <- na.approx(x,na.rm=FALSE)
         y <- na.approx(y,na.rm=FALSE)
})
```

Comment: @Fairy You can delete `library(data.table)`. In whole code `data.table` has not use anywhere. Also the output `big.data` is a data frame (check `is.data.frame(big.data))`. Since your date is varying, you can remove the line `dates <- paste0(1:2,'-1-01')` and  generate sequence of date variable using `seq(as.Date(date,format),as.Date(date,format),by = "day")`.

Comment: `Error in as.Date.default(date, format) : 
  do not know how to convert 'date' to class “Date”`
It's giving me the error when I am creating the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Try this using xts. I used some kind of different data to 'see' the results:

```
indata <- read.table(text='x    y    date    time
1    2    1-1-01  15:00
2    2    1-1-01  15:19
                      2    5    1-1-01  17:00
                      3    1    1-1-01  17:05
                      3    1    1-1-01  18:00
                      3    1    1-1-01  18:20
                      5    7    1-1-01  21:05
                      6    6    1-1-01  21:08
                      2    6    1-1-01  22:00
                      6    3    1-1-01  23:11
                      9    2    2-1-01  1:00
                      9    2    2-1-01  1:21
                      6    1    2-1-01  4:29
                      ', header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors = F)


library(xts)
xt <- strptime(paste(indata$date,indata$time),
               "%d-%m-%y %H:%M")
its=xts(x = indata[,1:2],
    order.by = xt,
    frequency = NULL)

period.apply(its, INDEX=endpoints(xt, on="minutes", k=20), FUN=mean) 

                      x   y
2001-01-01 15:19:00 1.5 2.0
2001-01-01 17:05:00 2.5 3.0
2001-01-01 18:00:00 3.0 1.0
2001-01-01 18:20:00 3.0 1.0
2001-01-01 21:08:00 5.5 6.5
2001-01-01 22:00:00 2.0 6.0
2001-01-01 23:11:00 6.0 3.0
2001-01-02 01:00:00 9.0 2.0
2001-01-02 01:21:00 9.0 2.0
2001-01-02 04:29:00 6.0 1.0
```